# Interpolation or other math formula

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, math, graphics

I have a math problem.

I am dealing with a graphics function that defines a gradient size. 
However this size is not in pixels but in a value ranging from 0 to 1.

I would like to find a formula to automatically determine the desired value for any size.

But just using my eyes I have discovered that

- if the size is 1000 pixels, the value should be ~0.96.
- if the size is 498 pixels, the value should be ~0.93.
- if the size is 306 pixels, the value should be ~0.9.
- if the size is 239 pixels, the value should be ~0.86.
- if the size is 175 pixels, the value should be ~0.79.
- if the size is 50 pixels, the value should be ~0.25.

Does anybody know a formula to calculate the size of a the value for a given pixel size? 
Or does anybody with a good mathematical understanding see the underlying formula right away?
The values are not perfectly right, I think. I had to use my eyes to determine which value is required to produce the gradient I need:

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula. It's not completely accurate, but I hope it's accurate enough:

```
FocusScale = 1 - 37.251 / uSize
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function pGetFocusScale(ByVal uSize As Double) As Double

    Dim d As Double
    d = 20 / (uSize / 2)

    Return 1 - d

End Function
```

It is used for

```
        Dim nPathGradientBrush As New PathGradientBrush(somePath)
        Dim dblFocusX As Double = pGetFocusScale(someRect.Width)
        Dim dblFocusY As Double = pGetFocusScale(someRect.Height)
        nPathGradientBrush.FocusScales = New System.Drawing.PointF(dblFocusX, dblFocusY)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathgradientbrush.focusscales%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Formula `FocusScale = 1 - 37.251 / uSize` looks more accurate. :)

Comment: @Dmitry Did you guess it from the values I posted, I mean are you a Beautiful Mind, or how did you get to know about 37.251?

Comment: Oh, no! I'm definitely not a Beautiful Mind! I've just tried several numbers manually in the Excel. Simple algorithm: if 37.2 gives results less than desired, and 37.3 gives more than desired, switch to the next digit: 37.2(?) :)

Comment: @Dmitry I would expect you to be right rather than me. I struggled with my formula for a long time. Regarding to my values, you are right. I think you should post your reply as the answer. It fits my question more accurately, I think.